# Problemas con Redux-Saga al hacer fetch a una API

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Redux-Saga trayendo una API llamada PokeApi y mandandolo al store de Redux.
El problema viene cuando al usar useSelector lo que hace es primero devolverme un arreglo vacio y luego de un tiempo me devuelve el arreglo con los datos. Debido a esto me ocurre un error al usar map para renderizar.
Aqui les dejo todo el código https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-cmqrsb
Espero que me puedan ayudar, me pase toda la tarde rompiendome la cabeza sin hallar solución alguna, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay que evaluar `pokemons.results` antes de devolver:

```
return (
    <div>
    {(!pokemons.results) ? null: pokemons.results.map(pokemon => (
        <h1>{pokemon.name}</h1>
    ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Con respecto al mensaje:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'pokemons.results.map')

El arreglo `pokemons` viene vacío, no tiene la propiedad `results`. Parece que así lo definiste en el `init state`:

```
const pokemonDefaultState = {
  pokemons: [],
  isLoading: false
};
```

ReactJS trata de devolver en el primer render, se da cuenta y es cuando manda el mensaje, esta podría ser la causa.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.